# Perl: LABEL defined inside the foreach loop, and issue coming on jumping to the LABEL using "goto LABEL"

Tags: perl, foreach, label, goto

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @content1=("sunTerio", "builds123", "build123_sunTerio", "glorai", "2131flow" , "build434_glorai");
my $tryVar;
&tty;


sub tty {
  foreach my $we (7..9) {
    $tryVar=1;
    LABEL34:                                           #### Line 12
    foreach my $i (@content1) {
        if (grep ((/sunTerio/i || /glorai/i), $i)) {   #### Line 14
            print "-----$i-----\n";
        }
    }

    if ($tryVar) {
        foreach my $r (1..5) {
           if ($r == 2 ) {
                $tryVar=0;
                goto LABEL34;
          
           }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Above is the code snippet. Here, when I am using "LABEL34" at the location where it is present (Line 12), then it is causing no issues. But when I am using "LABEL34" at the "Line 14", then it is causing issue with the (warning + error) message:

**Use of "goto" to jump into a construct is deprecated at pl.pl line.
Can't "goto" into the middle of a foreach loop at pl.pl line 14.**

Why is it so that when I am using LABEL34 at line 14, then only issue is coming; and not when the LABEL34 is at current position (Line 12), although both scenarios are under the foreach loop?

Thanks!

Comment: If you goto line 14 the loop initialization variable `my $i` is undefined. What value would you like `$i` to have? According to [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Goto) : *"It may not be used to go into any construct that requires initialization, such as a subroutine or a foreach loop."*

Comment: In one case (line 14) your are jumping out of one loop and inside another one - which has no clearly defined state of the iterator at the moment. In the other case (line 12) you are just jumping out of a loop but not into another one - you stay in the same outer loop instead. Just try to explain what behavior you would expect in both cases - with line 12 it is clear but with line 14 it is unclear what you expect the inner loop variable to be.

Comment: Buddy, you are going inside the completed loop using goto function. That's why, you are getting error. Based on $i variable only you are grepping the value. So, it won't workout. Instead of asking about the error. Please provide the detail of the requirement. it will help us to provide the different approach

Comment: @Rajesh, I understand why at line 14, the error is coming. But, unable to get why the error doesn't come when using the label at line 12, as again we are jumping inside the foreach loop.

Comment: @HåkonHægland,  I understand why at line 14, the error is coming. Obviously because initialization of $i is not there. But, unable to get why the error doesn't come when using the label at line 12, as again we are jumping inside the foreach loop

Comment: @PPP *"as again we are jumping inside the foreach loop"* Yes but now the loop is not finished, you are currently inside the outer loop when you jump, so `$we` is defined

Comment: Above all, there is no need for a `goto` for that.  There are other ways to rerun that line-12 loop if some condition is met futrher down. (If that's your objective.) An example: put them in a block and use `redo`.

Comment: It used to be said about `goto` that it encourages creating "spaghetti code" (going back and forth, being hard to follow). I would not recommend using it.

Comment: `perldoc -f goto` says "The author of Perl has never felt the need to use this form of goto". I guess this goes for most Perl programmers.

Comment: Tip: `grep ((/sunTerio/i || /glorai/i), $i)` is a bad way of writing `$i =~ /sunTerio|glorai/i`

Answer (score 2):

The foreach loop in question is this one:

```perl
foreach my $i (@content1) {
   ...
}
```

Jumping from outside of the foreach loop into its body makes no sense.

It makes no sense logically. A foreach loop body is executed for each item of a list. This loop body would be executed without an item.

It makes no sense practically. It would skip the evaluation of `@content1` and the initialization of `$i`. Using `$i` would be undefined behaviour. And when you reach the end of the loop, what then? How can you check if you've reached the end of a list you never created in the first place?

It should ever have been allowed, and it was surely not intentional.

I can't suggest an alternative to placing the label on line 14 because you haven't said what you are trying to do. (I would normally be able to guess, but that simply makes no sense.)